# How do I locate the "form" and "action" details of a Google Forms so that I can customize it

Tags: google-forms

How do I locate the "form" and "action" elements of this google form example [Example Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScDtxn0k4_Lz75CplgXD0h4PsHCY0MQSOzhmochktNjfzftfQ/viewform?usp=sf_link)

I have used Inspector (F12) in Chrome then the section Elements, but cannot find anything that I can copy and paste as an action into my own form.

Suggestions?

Comment: pls explain what are you trying to do... 
see the source code of the page and getting the "action" param of the form can easily be done... but apparently not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selector Gadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/selector%20gadget) - visit link for details.

Selector Gadget is an open source Chrome Extension that makes CSS selector generation and discovery on complicated sites a breeze.

Comment: How should that help?

Comment: I need the "action" info.